# Having an object move to more than one place using tween class in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

Hi I am trying to make an object, in this case 'ship_mc', move to 3 different points on a screen, but i want to use the tween class. I'm not sure why its not working, any help would be greatly appreciated. 
my code looks like this

```
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var myTween01:Tween = new Tween(this, "x", Regular.easeIn, 1416, 973, 4, true);
var myTween02:Tween = new Tween(this, "y", Regular.easeIn, 206, 446, 4, true);
var myTween03;
var myTween04;
var myTween05;
var myTween06;


myTween01.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);
function onFinish(e:TweenEvent):void {
myTween03:Tween = new Tween(this, "x", None.easeIn, 973, 695, 4, true);
myTween04:Tween = new Tween(this, "y", None.easeIn, 446, 222, 4, true);

}

myTween04.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish1);
function onFinish1(e:TweenEvent):void {
myTween05:Tween = new Tween(this, "x", None.easeIn, 695, 374, 4, true);
myTween06:Tween = new Tween(this, "y", None.easeIn, 222, 239, 4, true);
}
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
Symbol 'ship_mc', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 15 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type fl.transitions:Tween to an unrelated type Class.
Symbol 'ship_mc', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 15 1188: Illegal assignment to class Tween.
Symbol 'ship_mc', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 16 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type fl.transitions:Tween to an unrelated type Class.
Symbol 'ship_mc', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 16 1188: Illegal assignment to class Tween.
Symbol 'ship_mc', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 22 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type fl.transitions:Tween to an unrelated type Class.
Symbol 'ship_mc', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 22 1188: Illegal assignment to class Tween.
Symbol 'ship_mc', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 23 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type fl.transitions:Tween to an unrelated type Class.
Symbol 'ship_mc', Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 23 1188: Illegal assignment to class Tween.
```

thanks, i know people will suggest using tweenlite, but i would like to know what the problem is here, otherwise I wont learn!

Answer (score 0):

The error messages you are receiving tell you the lines where the problems are occuring: 15, 16, 22 and 23:

```
15: myTween03:Tween = new Tween(this, "x", None.easeIn, 973, 695, 4, true);
16: myTween04:Tween = new Tween(this, "y", None.easeIn, 446, 222, 4, true);

22: myTween05:Tween = new Tween(this, "x", None.easeIn, 695, 374, 4, true);
23: myTween06:Tween = new Tween(this, "y", None.easeIn, 222, 239, 4, true);
```

Your code for the first two tweens works fine, so what is the only difference between the first two, and the rest of the tweens?  The way you declared them.  You need to declare `myTween03`, `myTween04`, `myTween05` and `myTween06` as tweens to prevent the errors from being thrown, as it thinks you are trying to initialise a default class as a tween otherwise. Change:

```
var myTween03;
var myTween04;
var myTween05;
var myTween06;
```

to

```
var myTween03:Tween;
var myTween04:Tween;
var myTween05:Tween;
var myTween06:Tween;
```

and initialize them the same way you did for the first and second tween:

```
myTween03 = new Tween(this, "x", None.easeIn, 973, 695, 4, true);
myTween04 = new Tween(this, "y", None.easeIn, 446, 222, 4, true);
```

This basically states the variables will be initialized as tweens later on in the code, and will prevent those errors from being thrown.

Comment: thanks, that makes the first two tweens animate, but then i get this error
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at NavigationEquiptment_fla::ship_mc_3/frame1()

Comment: Something is not referenced correctly, did you alter the code for `myTween05` and `myTween06` as well?

Comment: i didnt have my eventlistener in my function so it didnt know what it was referencing, d'oh! thanks very much!

Comment: No problem =) (If you think the answer was helpful by the way you should up-vote or accept it as the correct answer).